# Eclipse Kepler destroyed after system crash

Tags: eclipse-adt, eclipse-kepler

After my system hung up while i was working with Eclipse and the Android-SDK-Plugin, Eclipse would not start anymore (some error with the android sdk). i then booted from cd, ran fsck to repair my system partition, started my system again and attempted to start eclipse kepler. it starts now, but it spams me with errors and i am unable to open any files.

with popup message: `...unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ToolsLocator`

and:
`The 'xtext.common.types.originalEditorSelector' extension from plug-in 'org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.shared' to the 'org.eclipse.ui.ide.editorAssociationOverride' extension point failed to load the editor association override class.
Plug-in org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.shared was unable to load class org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.shared.SharedCommonTypesExecutableExtensionFactory.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.shared (477)`

and many more, it just seems like something is very wrong. I would rather not reinstall everything, because i did some configurations to Perforce and other Plug-ins that i cannot remember very good. Is there any other reasonable attempt to solving this?

Comment: If you didn't understand the configurations and plugins, I would recommend reviewing them. It's easy to find ourselves in these nasty situations when we don't understand what we're using. Maybe a reinstall is best in the long term. Sorry - I know you're hoping for a quick fix.

Comment: Try specifying the `-clean` option on the Eclipse command or in the `eclipse.ini`